# I have a flask script to create APIs but can not connect to SQL Server Express with Windows passthrough

Tags: python, authentication, flask, iis, sql-server-express

I'm kind of new to this, but I wrote a flask script to present a Rest API. I'm using sqlalchemy and SQL Server Express is installed locally.

I am connecting using `sqlalchemy.create_engine`:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server/mydatabase?driver=SQLServer?Trusted_Connection=yes')
connection = engine.connect()
```

and I keep getting this error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Cannot open database "mydatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405) StdOut: StdErr:

What weird is I'm using the same connect string to upload the csv files to the database and it works fine. The only difference I can think of between this script and the other one is that this one is using IIS.

I'm running Windows Server 2012, Python 3.6, SQL Server 2012 Express

Comment: And if you use the same login with SSMS have you error??

Comment: And check on your Server Properties if you have checked Sql Server And Windows Autenthication Mode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by using this connection string instead.

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@DSNname")
```